# Trying to understand the disjoint union

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm currently studying some basic topology and have come across the disjoint union used in the definition of a covering. I found this particular statement: $X\cup{X\times{\{0\}}}=X\times{\{0\}}$. How can the union of points in X and pair of points in $X\times{\{0\}}$ make sense?

Surely you'd end up with a set containing all the points in X and all the points in X each paired with the point $\{0\}$.

Comment: Unless they meant $(X\cup X)\times \{0\}$.  But, yeah, if they meant what you suspect, that's a lousy source.

Comment: usually, the *disjoint union* of two sets $X,Y$ is $X \times \{ 0 \} \cup Y \times \{ 1 \}$.